# Change Length of PDF form AcroField using iText

Tags: itext, maxlength

I am filling pdf template using iText api. I am not able proper text in one textfield.

[image: Image of textbox in question]

It has boxes like this image.I have to fill one character in each box. When I am trying to set value it taking whole value in initial 3 box only.

Can anybody guide me how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Can you provide both your code (in which you try to set the value) and the PDF itself?

Comment: I am setting the value in form field using setField method only as described below : form.setField("Employee_No","123456789"); And one more thing I have two pdf templates secured and unsecured. In secured it is coming properly but in unsecured it is not coming properly.I dont know why it is happening like this.

Comment: Share the PDFs. Sounds like one of your forms defines a maximum length and has a "comb" flag for the field. The other probably hasn't. Don't make us guess. Share the PDF.

Comment: Thanks Bruno. I am also thinking in the same direction and sorry I cannot share the pdf files as its highly confidential. Can you please guide me how can I set comb property for particular existing form field using itext api ?